# Yahoo Finance - Python Web Scraper - Key Statistics and Financial Statements

Tags: python, scraper, yahoo-finance

I am fairly new to programming, and this is my first project after reading various guides. I am trying to scrape data from the Yahoo Finance Key Statistics page and Financial Statements (ie. http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=GOOG+Key+Statistics). The links to the financials is at the bottom of the key statistics page. The code for the key statistics function seems to work.

But for the statement function, the entry variable used in pattern3 does not obtain negative values. The problem is especially apparent for the cash flow statement. For negative values, entry should look like

```
entry = '<td align="right">(.+?)</td>'
```

Am I approaching this correctly? Is there a simple way obtain all the values of the financial statements and put them into a list?

My Code in Python 2.7:

```
import urllib
import re

keystat = '<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">(.+?)</td>'
date = '<th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-        weight:bold">(.+?)</th>' #obtain the date; only works for income statement
total = '<strong>(.+?)&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>' #obtain data for any totals from statements
entry = '<td align="right">(.+?)&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>' #obtain data for any entries on     statements that are not totals


def keystatfunc(symbol):
    url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=' + symbol + '+Key+Statistics'
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="yfs_j10_' + symbol + '">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    pattern2 = re.compile(keystat)
    marketcap = re.findall(pattern, htmltext) 
    keystats = re.findall(pattern2, htmltext)
    return (marketcap + keystats[1:31]) #creates a list with all the data on key statistics page)


def statement(symbol, period, statementtype): #period: "quarter" or "annually"; statementtype: is, bs, or cf (income statement, balance sheet, cash flow statement)
    if period == "quarterly" and statementtype == "bs":
        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=' + symbol
    elif period == "annual" and statementtype == "bs":
        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=' + symbol + '&annual'
    elif period == "quarterly" and statementtype == "is":
        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=' + symbol + '&annual'
    elif period == "annual" and statementtype == "is":
        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=' + symbol + '&annual'
    elif period == "quarterly" and statementtype == "cf":
        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cf?s=' + symbol + '&annual'
    elif period == "annual" and statementtype == "cf":
        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cf?s=' + symbol + '&annual'
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    pattern = re.compile(date)
    pattern2 = re.compile(total)
    pattern3 = re.compile(entry)
    dates = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
    totals = re.findall(pattern2, htmltext)
    entries = re.findall(pattern3, htmltext)
    return (dates + totals + entries)



print keystatfunc("goog")

print statement("goog", "annual", "cf")
```

Comment: Why not use their API?

Comment: Or at least something designed for screen scraping, such as [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the method you are using to extract the info is the most reliable way but I changed your code a little bit to capture the info you need. I updated the regular expression to check for parenthesis and added a section at the end to replace

```
    import urllib
    import re

    keystat = '<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">(.+?)</td>'
    date = '<th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-        weight:bold">(.+?)</th>' #obtain the date; only works for income statement
    total = '<strong>(.+?)&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>' #obtain data for any totals from statements
    entry = '<td align="right">(\(?.+?\)?)</td>' #obtain data for any entries on     statements that are not totals


    def keystatfunc(symbol):
        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=' + symbol + '+Key+Statistics'
        htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
        htmltext = htmlfile.read()
        regex = '<span id="yfs_j10_' + symbol + '">(.+?)</span>'
        pattern = re.compile(regex)
        pattern2 = re.compile(keystat)
        marketcap = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
        keystats = re.findall(pattern2, htmltext)
        return (marketcap + keystats[1:31]) #creates a list with all the data on key statistics page)


    def statement(symbol, period, statementtype): #period: "quarter" or "annually"; statementtype: is, bs, or cf (income statement, balance sheet, cash flow statement)
        if period == "quarterly" and statementtype == "bs":
            url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=' + symbol
        elif period == "annual" and statementtype == "bs":
            url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=' + symbol + '&annual'
        elif period == "quarterly" and statementtype == "is":
            url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=' + symbol + '&annual'
        elif period == "annual" and statementtype == "is":
            url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=' + symbol + '&annual'
        elif period == "quarterly" and statementtype == "cf":
            url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cf?s=' + symbol + '&annual'
        elif period == "annual" and statementtype == "cf":
            url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cf?s=' + symbol + '&annual'
        htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
        htmltext = htmlfile.read()
        pattern = re.compile(date)
        pattern2 = re.compile(total)
        pattern3 = re.compile(entry)
        dates = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
        totals = re.findall(pattern2, htmltext)
        entries = re.findall(pattern3, htmltext)
        entriesFixed = []
        for e in entries:
            entriesFixed.append(e.replace('&nbsp;',''))
        return (dates + totals + entriesFixed)



    print keystatfunc("goog")
```